# unable to ping across dell 3048 switch

Tags: routing, switch, ip, ping, dell

We have installed a new Dell 3048 switch onto an internet connection with 2 routed IP blocks. 
The usable IP blocks are 144.121.77.32/29 and 144.121.77.160/28. 
They are routed through  104.129.88.70/30.

The switch is directly connected to the provider line. There is a PC directly connected to the switch. It is statically configured with 144.121.77.38. This PC *is* able to surf the internet. However, I cannot ping the PC from the switch or from the outside world. I can ping outside internet addresses from the switch.

I feel like i'm missing something simple, but i'm tired of banging my head on it.

Entire config:

```
configure
vlan 8-9,88,255
exit
vlan 8
name "Internet Side"
exit
vlan 9
name "DMZ Side"
exit
vlan 88
name "P2P connection"
exit
ip telnet server disable
hostname "Alb3048-LighttowerDMZ"
slot 1/0 7    ! Dell Networking N3048P
stack
member 1 5    ! N3048P
exit
ip routing
interface vlan 1 1
ip address 10.66.127.8 255.255.255.0
ip address 10.66.112.143 255.255.248.0 secondary
exit
interface vlan 8 3
ip address 144.121.77.33 255.255.255.240
exit
interface vlan 9 4
ip address 144.121.77.161 255.255.255.224
exit
interface vlan 88 5
ip address 104.129.88.70 255.255.255.252
exit
interface vlan 255 2
exit
ip default-gateway 104.129.88.69
ip route 144.121.77.32 255.255.255.240 vlan 88
ip route 144.121.77.160 255.255.255.224 vlan 88
ip route 10.66.127.0 255.255.255.0 vlan 1
ip route 10.66.112.0 255.255.248.0 vlan 1
no passwords min-length
**usernames removed**
line ssh
exec-timeout 600
exit
ip ssh server
!
interface Gi1/0/1 Connection to Lighttower DIA
switchport access vlan 88
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/3
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/4
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/5 Connection to test PC
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!                 
interface Gi1/0/6
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/7
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/8
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/9
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/10
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/11
switchport access vlan 8
exit              
!
interface Gi1/0/12
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/13
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/14
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/15
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/16
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/17
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/18
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/19
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/20
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/21
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/22
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/23
switchport access vlan 8
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/24
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/25
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/26
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/27
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/28
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!                 
interface Gi1/0/29
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/30
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/31
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/32
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/33
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/34
switchport access vlan 9
exit              
!
interface Gi1/0/35
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/36
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/37
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/38
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/39
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/40
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/41
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/42
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/43
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/44
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/45
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/46
switchport access vlan 9
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/47
channel-group 99 mode active
exit
!
interface Gi1/0/48
channel-group 99 mode active
exit
!
interface port-channel 99
description "Uplink to ****CORE (Gi0/47-8)"
switchport mode trunk
exit
snmp-server engineid local 800002a203f8b15633f31e
**identifying snmp config removed**
snmp-server enable traps dvmrp
snmp-server enable traps pim
snmp-server enable traps captive-portal
snmp-server enable traps captive-portal client-auth-failure
snmp-server enable traps captive-portal client-connect
snmp-server enable traps captive-portal client-db-full
snmp-server enable traps captive-portal client-disconnect
eula-consent support-assist reject
eula-consent hiveagent reject
exit
```

---

```
Alb3048-LighttowerDMZ#ping 8.8.8.8
 Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 0 bytes of data:

Reply From 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq = 0. time= 6002 usec.
Reply From 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq = 1. time= 5710 usec.
Reply From 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq = 2. time= 5672 usec.
Reply From 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq = 3. time= 5937 usec.

----8.8.8.8 PING statistics----
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (msec) min/avg/max = 5/5/6

Alb3048-LighttowerDMZ#ping 144.121.77.38               
 Pinging 144.121.77.38 with 0 bytes of data:

----144.121.77.38 PING statistics----
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip (msec) min/avg/max = <10/<10/<10
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of your configuration.

Comment: Can your switch receive ARP requests on the port it is connected to the PC ?

Comment: Firewall on the PC?

Comment: ARP shows the PC just fine.
144.121.77.38    DC4A.3E7A.6215     Vl8             Dynamic    0h  0m 10s

Comment: Commands that would be useful "show ip route" on the switch and "route print" on the windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ping but can't be pinged your routing and ARP is fine. There must be something filtering the echo request/reply. Local or network firewall maybe?

Comment: Checking the PC config now.  
(unfortunately I did not initially set up this configuration)

Comment: Thanks to lovely corporate admin settings, I cannot turn off the windows firewall on the PC... however, I'm not convince that is the issue because there is a sonicwall also connected to the switch on 144.121.77.34, and it is pingable from the switch. but not from the outside world.

Comment: If the network is not under your control your question is off-topic here...

Comment: I am the engineer for the network. I have full control over the switch (and the sonicwall). 
I am not the sysadmin for the domain security properties. 
I can try to find a PC that is not on the domain to connect up, and remove the win firewall.

Comment: We connected a non domain laptop with win firewall disabled and assigned it the same .38 IP. Pings are working fine from the switch and the outside world. Thank you for the help.